# Histogram bars in different colors with the values on top

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I have this data file (`TotalDurationBarPlot.dat`):

```
Indexed list 934
Tree list 3692
Array list 12274
Linked list 48188
```

What I wish to achieve is a histogram chart with 4 bars: one for **Indexed list**, one for **Tree list**, one for **Array list**, one for **Linked list**. My requirements are:

1. Each bar has it's unique color,
2. On top of each bar, there is a number denoting the height of the bar. (For example, above the **Tree list**, there is **3692**.)
3. It would be nice to have a legend on a light gray background with a thin black legend border at the top right corner.

**My current attempt**

As of now, my data file looks like:

```
# ILL TL AL LL
934 3692 12274 48188
```

... and my gnuplot script looks like:

```
set title font "Monospaced,13" 'Total duration'
set grid
set key right top
set style data histograms
set style histogram cluster gap 2
set style fill solid border 2
set xtics format ""
set grid ytics
set ylabel "Milliseconds"
set yrange [0:70000]
# set boxwidth 0.5 relative
# set label "Array list\n134908 ms" at graph 0.145,0.9

ArrayListColor   = "#491d75";
IndexedListColor = "#b32929";
LinkedListColor  = "#d49435";
TreeListColor    = "#12520b";

plot 'TotalDurationBarPlot.dat' using 1 title "Indexed list" linecolor rgb IndexedListColor, '' using 2 title "Tree list" linecolor rgb TreeListColor, '' using 3 title "Array list" linecolor rgb ArrayListColor, '' using 4 title "Linked list" linecolor rgb LinkedListColor, '' u 0:1:1 with labels offset -6.0,-100.0 title ""

set terminal png size 650,350 enhanced font "Monospaced,13"
set output 'TotalDuration.png'
replot
exit
```

It produces:

[image: List comparison]

**PS**

The linked question does not address my needs here. My requirements are:

1. A legend box with (RGB) color for the legend border and background,
2. The thickness of the legend border,
3. The color of the bars,
4. The `y`-value of each bar must be typeset above the respective bar,
5. Minimum change in my current implementation.

(Finally, I cannot follow the code in the linked question.)

Comment: You don't need histogram, you should use your original data and plot a simple bar chart (`with boxes`) and variable color. Plot the numbers as labels on top of the bar with some offset. Legend border is a different topic, please stay focused to _one_ topic. Just do a simple SO search with `[gnuplot] legend box background`.