# gnuplot histogram: assign different colors to different bars

Tags: bar-chart, gnuplot, histogram

I have the following `gnuplot` script:

```
set title font "Monospaced,13" 'Total duration'
set terminal png size 650,350 enhanced font "Monospaced,13"
set grid
set key right top
set style data histograms
set style histogram cluster gap 2
set style fill solid border 2
set xtics format ""
set grid ytics
set ylabel "Milliseconds"
set yrange [0:70000]

ArrayListColor   = "#491d75";
IndexedListColor = "#b32929";
LinkedListColor  = "#d49435";
TreeListColor    = "#12520b";

plot 'TotalDurationBarPlot.dat' using 1 title "Indexed list" linecolor rgb IndexedListColor, '' using 2 title "Tree list" linecolor rgb TreeListColor, '' using 3 title "Array list" linecolor rgb ArrayListColor, '' using 4 title "Linked list" linecolor rgb LinkedListColor, '' u 0:1:1 with labels offset -6.0,-100.0 title ""

set output 'TotalDuration.png'
replot
exit
```

The data file `TotalDurationBarPlot.dat` is:

```
# ILL TL AL LL
934 3692 12274 48188
```

... and it produces:

[image]

Q: I would like to color the four bars. How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use histogram plotting style if you have a simple bar chart which you can simply draw `with boxes`?
And why don't you stay with the data format as in your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76320306/7295599)?

This could also be of interest (almost duplicate): [gnuplot: Colour-coding specific / individual histogram bars](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75249176/7295599)

*Edit: even simpler, add another column with the hexadecimal RGB color code.*

Further reading: `help int`, `help xticlabels`, `help linecolor variable`, `help colorspec`.

**Script:**

```
### bar chart with variable box color
reset session

$Data <<EOD
"Indexed list"    934   0xb32929
"Tree list"      3692   0x12520b
"Array list"    12274   0x491d75
"Linked list"   48188   0xd49435
EOD

set style fill solid 1.0
set boxwidth 0.8
set key noautotitle
set grid x,y
set tics out
set yrange[0:60000]

plot $Data u 0:2:3:xtic(1) w boxes lc rgb var, \
        '' u 0:2:2 w labels offset 0,0.7
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Close, but no cigar. On Windows gnuplot 5.4.7, an 0 bytes long PNG is generated. On Linux gnuplot 6.1, gnuplot complains that there is no `png` terminal available even though it is listed in the list of supported terminals.

Comment: @coderodde 1. use `set term pngcairo` 2. add a `set output` as the last line.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem persists: on windows gnuplot 5.4.7, all of the terminals `png`, `pngcairo` and `svg` produce empty files. The LInux gnuplot 6.1 does not support the `pngcairo` to begin with. However, when I run the script from the command line, it flashes prompty the plot and it appears to be what I want, so I guess we are getting closer.

Comment: @coderodde phew, maybe remove the `exit` at the end (why do yo need this?). Maybe gnuplot closes before it can close the output file. Well, if I save the script file as text file, e.g. "myPlot.gp" and in the gnuplot console type `load 'myPlot.gp'`.  The sequence is `set output 'myPNG.png'; plot ... ; set output # to close the PNG file` Have you put `set output` at the end? This should work fine.

Comment: I found another solution: I set the terminal to `wxt`, run the gnuplot script after which the plot pops up in a window.  Then, I just save the file in the window to a desired PNG file.

Comment: All in all, thank you for your patience!

Comment: @coderodde finally! Well, it's not the idea of the pngcairo terminal to use wxt and save it manually via user dialog as PNG.

Comment: Finally!? Let me tell you: it’s hard to navigate in the maze of information when you have severe ADD and schizophrenia that requires extensive sedative medication.

Comment: @coderodde ok, I understand. I agree that gnuplot documentation and examples are sometimes really a maze to find the right information. But it is "amazing" what it can do ;-)